# Why do I have to run `setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))` twice for it to work in R?

Tags: r, working-directory

`setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))` is used to set the working directory as the foder containing the current script.

I have noticed that I have to run twice for it to work, when running line by line (with CTRL + ENTER).

Why?

Does it work when sourcing the file (CTRL + SHIFT + S)?

Comment: it worked for me on one try, what version of rstudioapi/rstudio do you have?

Comment: @Mike  `rstudioapi` version ‘0.14’

Comment: RStudio 2022.12.0 Build 353

Comment: ok I am using rstudio 2022.07.2+576 so that might be a possible issue I will update later and see if I can reproduce the error

Comment: I can't reproduce the error on the new rstudio, I am running the code on a windows machine fyi

Comment: I am on Windows to